# Where Did This Method Come From in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have been following a tutorial on SpriteKit, and for the life of me, I don't know where this one method comes from.  In a StartGameLayer, I have this code in its entirety:

```
#import "StartGameLayer.h"

@interface StartGameLayer()
@property (nonatomic, retain) SKSpriteNode* playButton;
@end


@implementation StartGameLayer

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        SKSpriteNode* startGameText = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"FlappyBirdText"];
        startGameText.position = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5f, size.height * 0.8f);
        [self addChild:startGameText];

        SKSpriteNode* playButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"PlayButton"];
        playButton.position = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5f, size.height * 0.30f);
        [self addChild:playButton];

        [self setPlayButton:playButton];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if ([_playButton containsPoint:location])
    {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(startGameLayer:tapRecognizedOnButton:)])
        {
            [self.delegate startGameLayer:self tapRecognizedOnButton:StartGameLayerPlayButton];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Where does the `setPlayButton:(SKSpriteNode* )` method get set?  In the help file it says it is declared in this file, but this is the only instance I see of it, and it is just driving me the tiniest bit nuts how this method is created.

Comment: When you create a property, like playButton, you get a getter and a setter method created for you. The setter is setPlayButton:. You get this with every property (if its's read-write).

Comment: whoever wrote this tutorial needs to fix the use of retain, under ARC it should be strong. It's not a problem (they are equivalent) but if the tutorial author is stuck in MRC thinking the logical consequence might be using assign where weak is more appropriate (they are not equal). Seen this too many times before.